# Unable to login to the website when there are multiple concurrent logins

Tags: spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, weblogic12c, owasp

We have a website which is developed in spring.JPA and has Oauth2 implemented,  and is deployed in Weblogic server 12.1.3,

I am trying to do penetration testing.So when I run the testing scanner(OWASP Zed) pointing to Oauth2  the scanner initiates requests trying to penetrate the website and the same time when I try to login to the website from browser the login page is reloaded on the sign in click and stays on the login page and when I try the same by stopping the scanner I am able to login successfully.

I tried to do multiple logins to the website using JMeter and I am facing the same behavior I was not able to login when the JMeter was running, 
It seems like when there is multiple requests to process something is going wrong.

I am trying to find what would be the issue here is it related to application or is it something related to Weblogic server.The application logs looks clean.

Any guidance is highly appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you not able to login more than one client session of same user? Eg: Login application from Chrome and Firefox browser at same time for user Alice.

Comment: I am able to login from different clients at same time as same user,but when the scanner or jmeter is running I am unable to login at all.

Comment: Can you check access.log of application or OAuth server to see whether all requests (either from scanner or jmeter or browser clients) reaches the server or not? Also check HTTP status codes of each request processed by the server.

Comment: I compared the requests using chrome developer tool between the good and the bad case and found that the
/login?code=fH8ShX&state=Cc244n is not made instead login page is returned.